# PHP - MySQL Parameters

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP and MySQL, i'm sorry if i asking lame question but i really need help.

I have this code:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT name, lat, lng 
  FROM markers HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

I need to know what is the '%s' and how to put a dynamic Where condition (sometimes it cames null, sometimes with OR conditions)

Comment: You should learns about prepared staments!

Comment: %s is a place holder for a string. Google for sprintf and you get a proper explanation

Comment: dynamic statments you can create with if else in php

Answer (score 0):

You don't use aggregation function so  .. you should use  where and not having

```
"SELECT name, lat, lng 
 FROM markers where distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
```

You use sprintf for print the string  and you pass %s the you should pass only a string  in the call (the other parameter are wrong)

```
 $query = sprintf("SELECT name, lat, lng 
  FROM markers HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
   mysql_real_escape_string($Your_string));
```

This is the query you provided

```
query = sprintf("SELECT name,imagem, lat, lng 
          FROM markers 
          WHERE %2$s HAVING distance < '%1$s' 
          ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",   
            mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat), 
            mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng), 
            mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat), 
            mysql_real_escape_string($radius),   
            mysql_real_escape_string($dynamicWhereCondition));
```

Like i said before You 
     don't have to use having .. (Having is a clause is SQL used  for filter aggregatio function that you don't have in your query)

don't have to use more then the vars you declare with % ...you declare 2 vars but the passing var are 5

And more  you declare the vars in a manner i think wrong %1s and %2s ..

then i  advise you to deepen your knowledge of SQL with the more straightforward cases of what you are using ..

I apologize if I added this in response but it was too difficult to manage with a comment

Comment: What do you mean "doesnt work."   have you an error?  or respect the real data in your db get wrong result ? ..

Comment: It doesnt return any results.. I already read some things about the sprintf ,i need have to pass 2 Params the Second is a dynamic Where condition and Still not working.. 

$query = sprintf("SELECT name,imagem, lat, lng FROM markers WHERE %2$s HAVING distance < '%1$s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($radius),
  mysql_real_escape_string($dynamicWhereCondition));

Comment: I have update the answer  .. and like i said in answer i suggest you a trial with amlre simple case for sql and php ..  when you receive the  answer comment me so i remove it because i don't think is useful ..